# Hibernate: Query list of objects in one-to-many relationship

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, hql

I have the following one-to-many relationship between a User and multiple TvShows:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
public class User {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "user_id", updatable = false, nullable = false)
private int userId;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "tvShowId", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
private List<TvShow> favourites;
}
```

where TvShow.java is:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "tvshows")
public class TvShow {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "id", updatable = false, nullable = false)
private int tvShowId;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "seasonId", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
private List<Season> seasons;
}
```

I want a method that would return a List containing the favourite tv shows when given a userId.

So far I have:

```
@Query("SELECT t FROM TvShow t WHERE t.id = :userId")
public List<TvShow> getFavourites(@Param("userId") int userId);
```

but this just returns the TvShow that has the same Id as the userId that I've passed as a parameter.

The database is generated completely by Hibernate and looks like this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yZFGL.png)

I know this should be a simple query but I'm at a loss!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have at least a couple of problems in your code.

Firstly, you are not defining the relation in the other entity. That is, you should tell to the TV show about the user if you are going to model the relation between entities:

```
@ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name="user_id", nullable=false)
private User user;
```

The next is related to the usage of `mappedBy`. You should define the name of the java property that the set maps to, like so:

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "user", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
private List<TvShow> favourites;
}
```

Here `user` is the property that we mapped in the previous step.

Comment: This does not answer my foremost question. What am I doing wrong in my query?

Comment: The issue with that is that in HQL you should use the names of the java properties, not table column names. There is no `id` property in your entity.

Comment: Why do I have to include the many to one relationship as well? Can't hibernate take care of that as well? It's very counter-intuitive to have a User field in my TvShow.java

Comment: If you want to use the mappedBy, that's one way.

Comment: Ok, this is absurd. Can you please give me an advice on how to map this one-to-many relationship so that I can easily query my data? This one-to-many + many-to-one is absurdly counterintuitive.

Comment: If you are not interested to model the entity relationship in java, the simplest way is to do a native query which will return all tvshows by given user id, which seems to be your need.

Comment: Nevermind, I did as you said with the minor tweak: I didn't add a private User user, but a private int userId instead. Otherwise I followed your logic and got what I wanted! I've also accepted the answer. Thank you for your patience!

Comment: @GeorgeCimpoies I am glad it helped. Cheers!